# Algorithm translate a number to String

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to design an algorithm where each number is encoded to an alphabet, for example:

> 1=A, 2=B, 3=C...26=Z

Given a set of numbers, I have to translate them to a combination of strings. For example:

> 123 can be translated to - ABC(123), AW(1 23) and LC(12 3)

Write an algorithm to find the combinations for number - 123123123.

Now here is what I wrote and I find it inefficient because of multiple "for" loops. Is there any better way I can rewrite this algorithm?

```
public class ValidCombinations {
    Map<Integer, String> mapping = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public void run() {
            String s = "123123123";

            /*Convert String to int[]*/
            char[] cArray = s.toCharArray();
            int[] input = new int[cArray.length];

            for (int i=0; i<cArray.length; i++) {
                    input[i] = Character.getNumericValue(cArray[i]);
            }

            Set<String> output = new HashSet<String>();

            for (int i='A'; i<='Z'; i++) {
                    mapping.put(i - 'A' + 1, String.valueOf((char)i));
            }

            for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
                    if (mapping.containsKey(input[i])) {
                            output.add(precombine(i, input) + mapping.get(input[i]) + postcombine(i, input));
                            if (i+1<input.length) {
                                    if (mapping.containsKey(input[i]*10 + input[i+1])) {
                                            output.add(precombine(i, input) + mapping.get(input[i]*10 + input[i+1]) + postcombine(i+1, input));
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }

            System.out.println(output);
    }

    public String precombine(int i, int[] input) {
            String residue="";

            for (int m=0; m<i; m++) {
                    residue += mapping.get(input[m]);
            }

            return residue;
    }

    public String postcombine(int i, int[] input) {
            String residue="";

            for (int k=i+1; k<input.length; k++) {
                    residue += mapping.get(input[k]);
            }

            return residue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ValidCombinations v = new ValidCombinations();
            v.run();
    }
```

}

> For '123' - [ABC, AW, LC]
>
> For '123123123' - [LCABCABC, AWABCABC, ABCAWABC, ABCLCABC, ABCABCLC, ABCABCABC, ABCABCAW]

Comment: As this is a working solution that you want to improve, this may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wouldn't say it's just better suited - it is a tailor made fit. "Here is working code - I want someone to review it and improve it."

Comment: In fact that this looks like a quiz-question, improving this algo wont go far. You probably need an *effecient* algo. If so, you might need to loose most of the hashmap, string concat, function calls, nested for (atleast partially) etc.

Comment: I disagree with the above comments. "What is an *efficient* algorithm for X?" is absolutely on-topic here, even if the OP has already found an *inefficient* algorithm. (And kudos to him/her for doing so and posting his/her effort!)

Comment: Number of solutions is o (fib (n)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is crying out for recursion. Here's a quick and dirty implementation that takes the input "number" in as a string and uses `substring()` to consume the digits. You could adapt it to use numerical methods to get the first (or first two) decimal digits from an integer if you prefer.

If you choose to work directly from an `int`, it would probably be easier to start at the end (working with the least-significant-digits) than at the beginning -- `lastDigit = number % 10; otherDigits = number / 10`

```
public List<String> encodings(String number) {
    List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
    addEncodings("", number, out);
    return out;
}

private void addEncodings(String prefix, String number, List<String> out) {
    if (number.length() == 0) {
        out.add(prefix);
    } else {
        addParsingNDigits(1, prefix, number, out);
        addParsingNDigits(2, prefix, number, out);
    }

}

private void addParsingNDigits(int digits, String prefix, String number, List<String> out) {
    if (number.length() >= digits) {
        char encodedChar = parseChars(number, digits);
        if (encodedChar >= 'A' && encodedChar <= 'Z') {
            addEncodings(prefix + encodedChar, number.substring(digits), out);
        }
    }
}

private char parseChars(String number, int length) {
    int intVal = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, length));
    return (char) ('A' + intVal - 1);
}
```

I don't think your solution will find all possible encodings -- I think you need some sort of stack to solve it. The solution above implicitly uses the execution stack, because of recursive method calls. Another solution could explicitly place objects representing "todo" calculations onto a stack data structure in the heap:

```
private static class StackItem {

    public StackItem(String prefix, String number) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String prefix;
    public String number;
}

public List<String> encodings(String number) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    Stack<StackItem> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(new StackItem("", number));
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        StackItem current = stack.pop();
        if (current.number.equals("")) {
            results.add(current.prefix);
        } else {
            addToStackTakingNChars(2, current, stack);
            addToStackTakingNChars(1, current, stack);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

private void addToStackTakingNChars(int n, StackItem current, Stack<StackItem> stack) {
    if (current.number.length() >= n) {
        char c = parseChars(current.number, n);
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            stack.push(new StackItem(current.prefix + c, current.number.substring(n)));
        }
    }
}
```

Although "println debugging" is generally a bad habit, it would probably be a good learning exercise to run these examples with some `println()`s to observe how it works.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could split the String in the middle (recursively), search for all combinations in both substrings and build the cross product. To not miss any combinations we have to also build the cross product for the two substrings you get by splitting in the middle with an offset of one. Something like this:

```
private static int[] values;

public static final Set<String> solve(String s) {
    values = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        values[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
    return solve(0, values.length);
}

private static final Set<String> solve(int start, int len) {
    Set<String> ret = new HashSet<>();
    if (len == 1) {
        ret.add("" + ((char)(values[start] - 1 + 'A')));
    } else if (len == 2) {
        ret.add("" + ((char)(values[start] - 1 + 'A')) + 
                     ((char)(values[start + 1] - 1 + 'A')));
        int n = values[start] * 10 + values[start + 1];
        if (n <= 26)
            ret.add("" + ((char)(n - 1 + 'A')));
    } else {
        int next = start + len / 2;
        cross(solve(start, next - start), solve(next, start + len - next), ret);
        cross(solve(start, next - start + 1), solve(next + 1, start + len - next - 1), ret);
    }
    return ret;
}

private static final void cross(Set<String> a, Set<String> b, Set<String> target) {
    for (Iterator<String> itr = a.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        String s = itr.next();
        for (Iterator<String> itr2 = b.iterator(); itr2.hasNext();) {
            target.add(s + itr2.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Btw. the solution for "123123123" are the following 27 strings: LCABCAW, LCABCLC, ABCLCABC, ABCLCAW, ABCAWLC, AWLCABC, ABCAWAW, ABCAWABC, ABCLCLC, ABCABCABC, LCAWLC, LCAWAW, AWABCLC, LCAWABC, AWABCAW, LCLCAW, AWABCABC, LCLCLC, LCLCABC, LCABCABC, AWAWLC, AWAWABC, AWAWAW, ABCABCLC, ABCABCAW, AWLCAW, AWLCLC.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the ascii value?

All you would need to do would be to convert the number to a `String` `Integer.toString(num)` and then run a `for-loop` through the `.length()` of the `String` and pull the `.charAt(i)` from the `String` convert that back to an `int` and then add 16 to it.  Then you would just need to cast to a `char`. like so:

```
int a = 123;
String str = Integer.toString(a);
char[] chars = new char[str.length()];
for(int i=0,n=str.length();i<n;i++){
     chars[i] = (char)(str.charAt(i)+16);
}
String message = String.valueOf(chars);
```

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is that 123 can be interpreted in 3 different ways (ABC, AW and LC), your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: It's also wrong, spits out `"qrs"` Should be: `chars[i] = (char) (str.charAt(i) - '1' + 'A');` - no magic ASCII numbers needed

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be done in o(fib(n+2)) time with a standard DP algorithm.
We have exactly n sub problems and button up we can solve each problem in o(fib(i)) time.
Summing the series gives fib (n+2).

If you consider the question carefullly you see that it is a fibunacci series.
I took a standart code and just changed it a bit to fit our conditions.

The space is obviously bound to the size of all solutions o(fib(n)).

Consider this code:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapping = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

List<String > iterative_fib_sequence(int input) {
    int length = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(input))) + 1;
    if (length <= 1) 
    {
        if (length==0)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else//input is a-j
        {
            return mapping.get(input);
        }
    }
    List<String> b = new List<String>();
    List<String> a = new List<String>(mapping.get(input.substring(0,0));
    List<String> c = new List<String>();

    for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) 
    {
        int dig2Prefix = input.substring(i-1, i); //Get a letter with 2 digit (k-z)
        if (mapping.contains(dig2Prefix))
        {
            String word2Prefix = mapping.get(dig2Prefix);           
            foreach (String s in b)
            {
                c.Add(s.append(word2Prefix));
            }
        }

        int dig1Prefix = input.substring(i, i); //Get a letter with 1 digit (a-j)
        String word1Prefix = mapping.get(dig1Prefix);           
        foreach (String s in a)
        {
            c.Add(s.append(word1Prefix));
        }

        b = a;
        a = c;
        c = new List<String>();
    }
    return a;
}
```